# How would I make a colored alert box in LaTeX?

Tags: boxes

I would like to make something similar to the following green alert box

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#alerts

I have tried various combinations of verbatim without success

Comment: I would use `mdframed` for this

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a color box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{pink}{\hbox to \textwidth{alert box\hfill}}
\end{document}
```

If you want the text to have a different color use,

```
\textcolor{brown}{your text...}
```

For a paragraph you can you `parbox` or `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{pink}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\lipsum[1]}}
\end{document}
```

If you want a bit of "padding"

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{pink}{\parbox{\textwidth}{%
  \vskip10pt
  \leftskip10pt\rightskip10pt
  \lipsum[1]
  \vskip10pt
 }
}
\end{document}
```